# Run WCF methods from a browser

Tags: c#, wcf

I am creating a very basic WCF service with C# in Visual Studio 2010. I want to know if I can run my methods directly from a browser by typing something like: `//localhost:49815/Service1.svc/methodName(parameterValue)`?

Here is the essence of my code.

Interface:

```
using ...
namespace WcfService1{   
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1{
        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet]
        string echoWithGet(string s);
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke]
        string echoWithPost(string s);
    }
}
```

Methods:

```
 public string echoWithGet(string s ){
            return "Get: "+s;
        }

 public string echoWithPost(string s){
            return "Post: " + s;
        }
```

Comment: just curious... did you try it?

Comment: See also: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412178.aspx

Comment: Yes, if by "try it" you are referencing calling the method via my suggested format.

Comment: You'll need to **show us** what server-side config you're using! Especially the **binding** is crucial - which one are you using??

Comment: @user2635032 you can do what you want with something *like* your suggested format, but not *exactly* the format you suggested; the link I gave includes an example of the right format.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Yes, you can call those methods in a browser, *if* your service is configured properly, though you have the URL syntax wrong.

To call WCF methods from a browser, you need to do two things:

- Use `[WebGet]` and `[WebInvoke]` attributes on your methods, which you have done.
- Use a `webHttpBinding` for the endpoint of your service and enable the `webHttp` behavior. See http://weblogs.asp.net/kiyoshi/archive/2008/10/08/wcf-using-webhttpbinding-for-rest-services.aspx for a sample configuration, but the relevant parts are:

  ```
   <service> 
      <endpoint behaviorConfiguration="webBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="MyServiceContract" /> 
  </service> 

  <endpointBehaviors> 
      <behavior name="webBehavior"> 
          <webHttp /> 
      </behavior> 
  </endpointBehaviors>
  ```

Once that is done, WCF will start listening for URL request and route them to your appropriate web methods. You can set up URL templates in your `WebGet` or `WebPost` attributes that map  URL segments to method parameters, if you want to make your URLs "cleaner", but that's optional. Otherwise, you pass parameters the same way you pass parameter to any other URL, using the parameter delimiter:

```
http://localhost:49815/MyService.svc/methodName?parameterName=value
```

Note that the default for a web-invoked method is a POST. Technically you *can* do these through a browser but it's much harder (you'd have to make a local HTML form, or use your Javascript console, or something similar), but the `WebGet` methods can be invoked just by requesting the correct URL.

Also, if your methods return anything more complex than a string, WCF will try to serialize it as JSON; you may need to 'view source' on the resulting page to see it.

Comment: This answer may be misleading, because it makes it sound like you can ONLY access WCF methods from a browser using a `webHttpBinding`. Is that the case? What about the `<enableWebScript/>` directive?

Comment: you need one more thing...uri

Answer (score 5):

This does not answer your question, but it will make your life a lot easier to make your service RESTful (or REST-like). While you can do that with WCF, I'd strongly recommend taking a look at [ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api).

There are also other alternatives available for creating RESTful services, such as [Nancy](http://nancyfx.org/) or [ServiceStack](http://www.servicestack.net/).

Answer (score 1):

A straight answer.
For GET Methods you can use a browser to view the result.
FOR POST Methods you cannot use Browser, if you are directly pasting your url for post method. 
In order to achieve POST you can either create a HTML FORM or use FIDDLER to see the result.