# Why are the functions in web service not working?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

Greeting, Currently i am working on a displaying the services in xml format in the browser.

However, it shows an empty page, is there an explanation why? firewall issue?
Here are all the files.

IProductService1.cs

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;


namespace WCFRESTfulService
{
// NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change     the interface name "IService1" in both code and config file together.
[ServiceContract]
public interface IProductService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet]
    List<product> GetAllProducts();

    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet]
    product GetProducts(string id);

}

}
```

ProductService1.svc.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;

namespace WCFRESTfulService
{
// NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change     the class name "Service1" in code, svc and config file together.
// NOTE: In order to launch WCF Test Client for testing this service, please   select Service1.svc or Service1.svc.cs at the Solution Explorer and start    debugging.
public class Service1 : IProductService1
{

    public List<product> GetAllProducts()
    {
        using(var db=new estocktakeEntities())
        {
            return db.products.ToList();
        }
    }


    public product GetProducts(string id)
    {
        Int32 _id = Convert.ToInt32(id);
        using(var db=new estocktakeEntities())
        {
            return db.products.SingleOrDefault(p => p.invtid == id);


        }


    }
}
}
```

Web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit     http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework"     type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection,     EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,     PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>

  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="myService.ProductService">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration=""     binding="webHttpBinding" contract="MyService.IProductService"></endpoint>        
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="restbehaviour">
      <webHttp/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<protocolMapping>
  <add scheme="https" binding="basicHttpBinding"/>
</protocolMapping>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="false" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"></serviceHostingEnvironment>
  </system.serviceModel>



  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
  </system.webServer>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Model1" connectionString="data source=CHRISPHAN-HP\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=estocktake;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /><add name="estocktakeEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/productmodel.csdl|res://*/productmodel.ssdl|res://*/productmodel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=CHRISPHAN-HP\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=estocktake;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /></connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

When i tested it using WCF test tool, the functions are working.

Tested on website 
[image: The service page which is working]

After adding the function into the url
[image: Get all product is not displaying]

Any suggestion will be a great help, Sorry for this long post.

-UPDATE-
 Still unable to run services in the browser, when it is possible in the youtube video.
Using 
VS2013 for web
SQL
IIS Express

Comment: do you have data in the db?

Comment: @Sajeetharan Yup the my db has record and it is working in the test client.

Comment: @Chris see your browser console what is there ?

Comment: @Mairaj sorry what are you referring to again? how can i show you that?

Comment: When you see empty page in browser press F12 and refresh page again then in console see the error.

Comment: Oh... it shows: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)" @Mairaj

Comment: It means you have error inside your service code.

Comment: I cant locate whats the error, sorry i am still new and learning. Anyone could located any error??

Comment: Error is in `GetAllProducts`. You can expand the console where it was showing error to see details.

Comment: i expand the console and its empty... Thats weird

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally browsers does not display xml results, To call WCF methods from a browser, you need need to create Restful service in WCF

The following link should help,

**[Run WCF methods from a browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18989423/run-wcf-methods-from-a-browser)**